# " ValueError: pyarrow.lib.Codec size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. "

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I've been using ColabPro to run some Machine Learning models for a few weeks now, and suddenly, today I've come across an error that has persisted, even without having changed the code in any instance. I have been researching what could have been the reason for this problem but I have not been successful, and this has effectively made it impossible for me to use ColabPro, and to continue my work.
Here is the error I have received:

```
      2 import numpy as np
      3 
----> 4 from . import (
      5     avro,
      6     binaryop,

cudf/_lib/avro.pyx in init cudf._lib.avro()

cudf/_lib/column.pyx in init cudf._lib.column()

cudf/_lib/scalar.pyx in init cudf._lib.scalar()

cudf/_lib/interop.pyx in init cudf._lib.interop()

ValueError: pyarrow.lib.Codec size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 48 from C header, got 40 from PyObject
```

Comment: Thank you for the heads up.   It seems something has changed in Colab again, and I'll work on fixing it and post it as a solution below.  In the mean time, you can try using Sagemaker Studio Lab (https://studiolab.sagemaker.aws/) and using this notebook to install RAPIDS: https://github.com/rapidsai-community/rapids-sagemaker/blob/main/RAPIDS-SageMaker.ipynb